# Typesafe Activator NoSuchMethodError

Tags: java, scala, playframework, typesafe-activator

I'm having an issue running Typesafe Activator. I had it working fine for a while on version 1.1.3. It was a Java Play project. Recently however it auto-updated to 1.2.1 and has stopped working.
First things first, my Java version is 1.7.0_25-b17. I'm running Windows 8.1 and running activator from PowerShell.

Here is the error output:

```
The system cannot find the file C:\Users\[my name]\.activator\1.2.3\activatorconfig.txt.
The system cannot find the file C:\Users\[my name]\.activator\activatorconfig.txt.
Checking for a newer version of Activator (current version 1.2.1)...
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: scala.util.matching.Regex.unapplySeq(Ljava/lang/CharSequence;)Lscala/Option;
        at activator.ActivatorLauncher.downloadLatestVersion(ActivatorLauncher.scala:164)
        at activator.ActivatorLauncher.checkForUpdatedVersion(ActivatorLauncher.scala:206)
        at activator.ActivatorLauncher.run(ActivatorLauncher.scala:27)
        at xsbt.boot.Launch$$anonfun$run$1.apply(Launch.scala:109)
        at xsbt.boot.Launch$.withContextLoader(Launch.scala:129)
        at xsbt.boot.Launch$.run(Launch.scala:109)
        at xsbt.boot.Launch$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Launch.scala:36)
        at xsbt.boot.Launch$.launch(Launch.scala:117)
        at xsbt.boot.Launch$.apply(Launch.scala:19)
        at xsbt.boot.Boot$.runImpl(Boot.scala:44)
        at xsbt.boot.Boot$.main(Boot.scala:20)
        at xsbt.boot.Boot.main(Boot.scala)
Error during sbt execution: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: scala.util.matching.Reg
ex.unapplySeq(Ljava/lang/CharSequence;)Lscala/Option;
```

This is also happening with a fresh download of activator. It happens whenever I try to run activator or activator ui. Other commands fail with similar messages, except for activator help, which runs fine. Does anyone know what's wrong here? Am I missing something? Theoretically Activator should run as long as I have JDK6+, right? I'm using the version that's supposed to include dependencies, and as far as I can tell, that missing method actually does appear to be there. This is really holding me up since I have to get back to work on that Play project.

Comment: Maybe it is using an older scala jar. Try to remove any older files (in .activator or .ivy2)

Comment: I don't see these directories, and I do have hidden files and folders visible. This is from a brand-new download of activator, so I haven't changed the version of Scala at all.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I had a similar (although not quite identical) error a few minutes ago; the workaround [described on this page](https://github.com/typesafehub/activator/issues/549) fixed it for me...

Comment: This answer is from 4 years ago and the link is broken! This is why we should report the actual solution, not just a pointer!

Answer (score 6):

deleting ~/.activator/version-0.properties

Answer (score 1):

I just figured it out - in my username directory (Windows 7 x64) there was a folder named ".sbt". 
In there was a folder named  "boot".
In there were a handful of scala folders, each folder a different version.
I deleted all of them except the latest scala version folder (scala-2.11.1).  Once I did that, Activator booted up successfully (right click on the Activator.bat file).